# SwiftUI navigate if ObservedObject property changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't for the life of me figure out how to only navigate if a property from my `ObservedObject` changes to meet a condition. ie when my state changes to some condition, navigate to the next screen.

I've used the `tag` and `selection` initializer on the `NavigationLink` but it `selection` requires a `Binding`, and I can't derive a `Binding` from the properties on my `ObservedObject` without using the `.constant()` initializer on `Binding` which is only an immutable value.

```
@ObservedObject var store: Store<AppState, AppValue>

NavigationLink(
   destination: SecondView(),
   tag: true,
   selection: store.shouldNavigate // Can't do this because I need a binding
)
```

How else are people implementing buttons that only navigate if a condition in their state is met? I'm trying to avoid using the `@State` because I want the navigation to depend on my app state not on a local state that I'm toggling based on some business logic

```
public final class Store<Value, Action>: ObservableObject {
    @Published public private(set) var value: Value
}
```

UPDATE:

So it looks like I should be able to create a binding but since `store.value` gives me `Binding<Value>` I get an error: `Generic parameter Subject cannot be inferred`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `shouldNavigate` a @Published property? That would expose a binding for it.

Comment: @Vlad because then I'd have to toggle it based on some business logic that I want elsewhere. I don't really want my validation logic in my view although it would let me have a published property in my view. Does that make sense?

Comment: “and I can't derive a Binding from the properties on my ObservedObject“. Why not? Put a dollar sign in front of the name of the observed object and you’ve got a binding. What’s the problem? `$store.shouldNavigate` should work, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Published properties should go in your view model, not your view.

Comment: @matt Hm, maybe it's the way my store is set up. I get "Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred" when I add the dollar sign. Maybe I need to look into this a little deeper. I simplified the store for the sake of the question but it's a little more complex in my actual app

Comment: @Vlad I'm using a redux type architecture where I don't really have classes and I know Published is only a property on classes

Comment: @Vlad My store is generic over some Value where Value is a struct representing my AppState. I updated the code above

Comment: Can you restrict your VM definition to `public final class Store<Value, Action>: ObservableObject where Value : Hashable`. NavigationLink requires selection to be hashable so it can compare it to `tag`, but your definition is too generic.

Comment: @Vlad Oh boy that might break everything, but maybe that's what's missing? EDIT: Still doesn't like that, still get the same error. I get a Binding<Hashable> with the same error above

Comment: Yes it sounds like a generic Observable might not be such a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

just remove `private(set)` in your model, `NavigationLink` will set `shouldNavigate` to false after navigation is completed, so it should not be `private(set)`

```
public final class Store<Value, Action>: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var value: Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I show you an important intermediate solution before generics. I think the key here is that `selection binding` requires `optional` binding. That's most hassles coming from.

```
            enum AppState: String{
        case none = "none"
        case red = "red"
        case blue = "blue"
        case green = "green"
        case purple = "purple"
    }


    enum AppValue: String{
        case none
    }

    public final class Store<V, A>: ObservableObject {
        @Published  var value: AppState? = AppState.none
       public var link :Color = Color.white
        init(value: AppState = .none,  link : Color = Color.white){
            self.link = link
            self.value = value
        }
    }

     struct TestView: View {
        @ObservedObject var store: Store<AppState?, AppValue>

        var viewStates: [Store<AppState?,AppValue>] =
            [Store(value: .red, link: Color.red),
             Store(value: .blue, link: Color.blue) ,
             Store(value: .green, link: Color.green),
             Store(value: .purple, link: Color.purple)  ]

    var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            ForEach(viewStates, id: \.value){ s in
                Group{
                NavigationLink(destination: s.link, tag: s.value!, selection: self.$store.value ){EmptyView()}
                    Button( s.value!.rawValue, action: {
                    self.store.value = s.value!})
                }}
        }
        }
    }
    }
```